# ASP.NET MVC - Insert into database after post method

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two `POST` methods, `UpdateData` and `UpdateTank`, that throw values from stored procedures from a database. I want to add these thrown values to the database table - that's why I'm trying to use the `POST` method `AddOrder`.

`AddController`:

```
public class AddController : Controller
{
    // GET: Add
    public ActionResult Index(SlurryListOfClass SlurryListOfClass)
    {
        if (SlurryListOfClass.MesData.BatchNumber == null)
        {
            SlurryListOfClass.MesData.MatNumber = "";
            ///stuff
            SlurryListOfClass.TankParam.PH = "";
        }

        return View(SlurryListOfClass);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateData(string order)
    {
        SlurryListOfClass olc = new SlurryListOfClass();

        //stuff
        return View("Index", olc);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateTank(string tank)
    {
        SlurryListOfClass slc = new SlurryListOfClass();

        //stuff

        return View("Index", slc);
    }

    //Post method to add order
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrder(SlurryListOfClass obj)
    {
        AddDetails(obj);

        return View();
    }

    private SqlConnection con;

    // To Handle connection related activities
    private void connection()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SlurryOrderEntStoProc"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    }

    // To add records into database 
    private void AddDetails(SlurryListOfClass obj)
    {
        connection();
        string sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNr", obj.InsertTable.OrderNr ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        //...
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", obj.InsertTable.Comment ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

`SlurryListOfClass` is my main model in which I store all the others.

`Index` view:

```
@model SlurryOrder2.Models.SlurryListOfClass

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateData", "Add", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
//Here I show two textboxes. The second one is the input parameter to the POST method UpdateTank.

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateTank", "Add", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // Here I have 20-30 texboxes. The part is completed thanks to the UpdateTank POST method and the part 
    // is filled by the user. I want to pass these values into database.
}

<div class="panel-footer panel-custom">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="addOrder">Add order</button>
</div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addOrder").click(function () {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                        url: "Add/Index", // Controller/View
                        data: { //Passing data
                            OrderNr: $("#txtOrder2").val(), //Reading text box values using Jquery
                            //...
                            Comment: $("#comment").val()
                        }

                    });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I tried many ways but I can't add values into database after POST methods `UpdateData` and `UpdateTank` start their "work". For example, I tried to return the object model from the POST method `UpdateTank` using `RedirectToAction` to the POST method `AddOrder`.

Comment: The overall flow here is *very* strange and confusing. You have forms which post to the server and do nothing but return back an empty object, returning the same view for a different URL (which itself is often problematic). Then in the AJAX call you're posting to the `Index` action, which doesn't add anything to a database and just returns the same view again. It doesn't look like you need those first forms and their corresponding actions. It looks like you just need a couple inputs and then have your AJAX operation post to `AddOrder`. Or am I missing something in your intent here?

Comment: I probably did some stupid things because this is my first project. I used the first forms to fill texboxes based on parameters from the stored procedures. Next, I want to add these filled textboxes to the database.

Comment: @KwiecMac Index is HttpGet on your AddController. But your ajax statement says, you are trying to invoke it via POST.

Comment: @sam: Since there's no explicit `[HttpGet]` on `Index` then it *would* still handle a POST request.  But in this code it does indeed appear to be mixing up which requests should go where and with what data.

Comment: @sam Now I see this error. Thanks to @David I turned it into: ```url: "@Url.Action("AddOrder", "Add")"``` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you don't need those previous forms or their corresponding controller actions.  (`UpdateData` and `UpdateTank`).  They're not actually doing anything, it's just a ton of overhead for what can be accomplished with simply this (styling and adding other markup as necessary, of course):

```
<input type="text" id="txtOrder2">
<input type="text" id="comment">
```

Or use a `<textarea>` instead if you like.  Of course, if you're binding to values in the returned model in `Index` then you can still use model helpers for that.  Maybe something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderNr, new { id = "txtOrder2" })
```

It's tough to tell how what you're returning in `Index` really relates to what you're trying to post to `AddOrder`.  But since you're manually posting using jQuery AJAX then you probably don't need a lot of the framework tools and can just display the data on the page using whatever markup you choose.

---

Aside from that, in your AJAX operation you're posting to the wrong controller action.  `Index` doesn't add anything to the database, `AddOrder` does.  Just change the URL:

```
url: "Add/AddOrder",
```

You can also use server-side helper code to generate the URL for you if you're unsure or if it might change relative to the view:

```
url: "@Url.Action("AddOrder", "Add")"
```

Comment: Please look on my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60077367/12008885

Comment: @KwiecMac: Please don't post an answer which isn't an answer.  You are encouraged to edit the question to include more information as needed.  As for what you're asking in that "answer", perhaps you at least need the `Html.TextBoxFor` to bind to a model being returned in `Index`?  If that's the case then you can still use that.  But why do you need the whole form?  Why do you need the `UpdateData` and `UpdateTank` controller actions?  What are those doing for you?

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't fit it as a comment. I guess I'm starting to understand that this Html.BeginForm, UpdateData e.t.c. is not necessary. I did it because I suggested opinions from the Internet and the environment. Thank you for calmly explaining this to me. I'm starting to redo the code :)